# How to mute: NOTE: Behavior of MACDH calculation has changed as of July 2017 - it is now 1/2 of previous calculated values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas/[stockstats](https://pypi.org/project/stockstats/) and calculating macd. After that I got some log like this:

```
NOTE: Behavior of MACDH calculation has changed as of July 2017 - it is now 1/2 of previous calculated values
```

How can I mute this log? I tried this but it didn't help:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code that generates the error so your problem can be reproduced. Thanks.

Comment: It's from https://pypi.org/project/stockstats/ (see last lines of page)